# Third tab's oncreateView is not called using android tab layout with view page adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I was looking at a project http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/
i put the logs to check the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` like

```
Log.d("Info","First Fragment oncreate method");  
Log.d("Info","Second Fragment oncreate method");  
Log.d("Info","Third Fragment oncreate method");
```

in FragmentOne,Two and three.

when i ran the project it initialized only first two tabs. 
**onCreate method of third fragment wasn't called**. while changing the tabs sometimes it shows **first tab as second tab and some time it shows second as first tab( i got to know by the log mentioned above)**. i don't know the reason behind.
I was trying to implement recycler view each for threee fragment and load data from the server. what it does is it show me data in the first fragment but the orther fragments were blank . i called the async class in the oncreate method. and onPostExecute i bind the recyclerview with its adapter.
please help me

Comment: The reason is 'FragmentPagerAdapter' will load the neighbouring fragments so it prints the log you have added

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi so what is the best way to call the async class to  load data from server when using tabs

Comment: One way is to get data in your hosting activity and then pass data using bundle to your fragments

Comment: ok thanks. i wlll try and let you know

Comment: any luck here? same problem here